# HKSCS (Hong Kong Supplementary Character Set) in UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

We have a client that needs some content importing into our system that includes HKSCS characters. Is this likely to be difficult to deal with?

Our system is entirely based around UTF-8 at the moment from the moment of import, through the processing we do, and right up to output for display to the user.

I'm afraid this is one of those situations where I'm not even sure I'm asking the right question! Any feedback welcomed greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode contains all the characters that HKSCS contains. Therefore any Unicode encoding, such as UTF-8, can encode any HKSCS character.

There is no such thing as an X (where X is charset or encoding, but it is even more wrong for encoding) character anyway. Characters do not exclusively belong to a single character set.